# On a css hover effect, not able to select/apply effect to a specific element?

Tags: html, css, hover, mouseover

I have an image with a div overlay. The div overlay appears on hover. ALSO on the hover, I want an animation effect. The problem is, the animation effect happens on the image AND the overlay, but I do not want the animation effect to occur on the overlay.

This code works, but I'm not able to prevent the animation from occurring on the overlay. What css code will make the animation effect happen ONLY on the image?

So in the code below, the css is working on the container-image, **but it is also happening on the extra-layer**. How to make this ONLY work on the container-image?

html

```
    <special class=“container”>
    <a href=“#" class=“container-link”>
    <img  src=“image.jpg" class=“container-image”> 
    <div class=“extra-layer”></div>
    </a>
    </special>
```

css

```
   #container {
        position: relative;
   }

    .container ::before {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-60%, -60%);
        transform: translate(-60%, -60%);
        opacity: .5;
    }

     .container :hover::before {
           -webkit-animation: circle .55s;
            animation: circle .55s;
     }
```

Comment: Remove the space before  :hover and :before

Comment: You're also likely to run into a world of hurt with the symbol `“`, use the standard parenthesis instead which is `"`, i.e. `<special class="container">`

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, thanks, but that didn't work. Nothing happens then.

Comment: Hi EGC, they are correct in the real code, I guess just a cut and paste issue, when I put the code on this page.

Comment: We'll need a much clearer explanation of what you want to happen + well need a minimal-reproducible-example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example / - if we're going to help. Here's a start: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/48u02ebf/

Comment: Hi sheriffderek, https://jsfiddle.net/8etjpgyb/5/, you will get the idea....  as you can see, the orange circle happens when you mouse over the bottom div... that is what I'm trying to prevent? It does happen on the image, which is good.

Comment: As I said, you need to explain it well. "code works... but doesn't work except..." - isn't a clear outline of the desired effect / even when I see your example.

Comment: If something is a descendent (inside of) the parent... it's going to trigger the hover. You can try using pointer-events none - but it's much more likely that most of what you're doing - needs to be done properly. A class name 'display' or 'container' - is the first problem. You'll need clearer naming - and clearer goals.

Comment: true, but in the OP, why isn't container-image good enough to specify when to activate the hover? thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code does not worked. i tested it through JSFiddle. I think what you want is something like this

[you can refer here for further information](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}

.image {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
opacity: 1;
}

.text {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
<img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
<div class="overlay">
<div class="text">Hello World</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Asad, if you add this to your code:
.display{  
padding-top:200px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);}
#container {  position: relative;
}
.container ::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-60%, -60%);
    transform: translate(-60%, -60%);
    opacity: 1;
}
.container :hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: circle .55s;
    animation: circle .55s;
}

Comment: @-webkit-keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

 100% {
width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes circle {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;}}

Comment: You will see the issue:  the orange circle ONLY appears in the display, while I want it to only happen on the image (not the display)

Comment: @user1864734 can you please share the link to your code. because what we understand from your problem statement is what we are providing you. Thanks

Comment: Hi Asad, take a look here...you see the orange circle happens twice. How to only show the center orange circle. thanks
https://codepen.io/trynn/pen/zYxZQbx

Comment: Hello @user1864734 thanks for providing the code url. I have gone through your code. first thing I had done is convert your code to CSS so that i can easily sort it out. because i dont have much grip on SCSS/SASS?LESS. anyways, the problem was when you hovered upon image the circle showed. and when you hovered on the title the second circle showed. now when you get to the name (hovered) a third circle showed (Continued...)

Comment: thanks, but on your codepen, the hover of the text display stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

The code i edited to show only the center circle is here. you can check it when you hover upon the image. the title and name.

HTML is same as yours. CSS is

```
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
body {
color: white;
font-family: 'helvetica-nue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
.gallery {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 20px;
}
.gallery li {
width: 421px;
min-height: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 255px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
}
.gallery li:nth-child(2) img {
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
.name {
transition-property:all;
transition-duration:.6s;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: white;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
position: absolute;
height:auto;
float:left;
width: 100%;
display: block;
top: 40%;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2;
}
.gallery li .name .title {
display: block;
text-transform: none;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 80%;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
transition-property: all;
transition-delay:.2s;
transition-duration:.9s;
}
.gallery li:hover img {
background-position: top top;
}
.gallery li img {
display: block;
width: 421px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
#gallery {
position: relative;
}
.gallery ::before {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
background: orange;
border-radius: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
opacity: 1;
}
.gallery li:hover::before {
-webkit-animation: circle 0.95s;
animation: circle 0.95s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
0% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
}
}
@keyframes circle {
0% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
opacity: 0;
}
}
```

[Here is the code Link](https://codepen.io/asad7880/pen/JjoNOqO). You might encounter that the transition effects of text has gone. but that can be resumed. check out the functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the code below. Run the snippet to see the result:

```css
.container-link{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}

.extra-layer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-link:hover img{
  animation: circle 0.55s;
}


@keyframes circle{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href='#' class="container-link">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" class="container-image" /> 
    <div class="extra-layer"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```